# Add words into a text slider css

Tags: css

I'm struggling to add more words at this slider.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  color:#999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:200px;  
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:45%;
  display:block;
}

#flip {
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#flip > div > div {
  color:#fff;
  padding:4px 12px;
  height:45px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
  animation: show 5s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
  background:#42c58a;
}
#flip div:first-child div {
  background:#4ec7f3;
}
#flip div:last-child div {
  background:#DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {margin-top:-270px;}
  5% {margin-top:-180px;}
  33% {margin-top:-180px;}
  38% {margin-top:-90px;}
  66% {margin-top:-90px;}
  71% {margin-top:0px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
  100% {margin-top:-270px;}
}

p {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#999;
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  Make 
  <div id=flip>
    <div><div>wOrK</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything</div></div>
  </div>
  AweSoMe!
</div>

<p>a css3 animation demo</p>
```

Works fine with 3 words but I need 7

After changing the html with this one

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  color:#999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:200px;  
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:45%;
  display:block;
}

#flip {
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#flip > div > div {
  color:#fff;
  padding:4px 12px;
  height:45px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
  animation: show 5s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
  background:#42c58a;
}
#flip div:first-child div {
  background:#4ec7f3;
}
#flip div:last-child div {
  background:#DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {margin-top:-270px;}
  5% {margin-top:-180px;}
  33% {margin-top:-180px;}
  38% {margin-top:-90px;}
  66% {margin-top:-90px;}
  71% {margin-top:0px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
  100% {margin-top:-270px;}
}

p {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#999;
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  Make 
  <div id=flip>
    <div><div>wOrK</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK2</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle2</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything2</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK3</div></div>
  </div>
  AweSoMe!
</div>
```

There no change and I don't find a way to reach my goal with the CSS :(

I don't need background etc ...

In fact I would love to have a div centered on my page with:
[My words] Text Slider [My words 2]
but with "Text Slider" align left with 7 words (or more) into the slider

Page test where I'm working on it : https://www.petrescue.do/test/

If anyone can help me with this... It would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited your question so that the code is here in the question instead of no some external site.  In the future please include runnable code examples in your questions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of this code:

```css
@keyframes show {
  0% {margin-top:-270px;}
  5% {margin-top:-180px;}
  33% {margin-top:-180px;}
  38% {margin-top:-90px;}
  66% {margin-top:-90px;}
  71% {margin-top:0px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
  100% {margin-top:-270px;}
}
```

You are only changing the `margin-top` to have 3 different values.  To see what I mean, I've removed the `overflow:hidden` and added a red border to the `#flip` element so you can see what is happening.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  color:#999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:200px;  
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:45%;
  display:block;
}

#flip {
  height:50px;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#flip > div > div {
  color:#fff;
  padding:4px 12px;
  height:45px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
  animation: show 5s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
  background:#42c58a;
}
#flip div:first-child div {
  background:#4ec7f3;
}
#flip div:last-child div {
  background:#DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {margin-top:-270px;}
  5% {margin-top:-180px;}
  33% {margin-top:-180px;}
  38% {margin-top:-90px;}
  66% {margin-top:-90px;}
  71% {margin-top:0px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
  100% {margin-top:-270px;}
}

p {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#999;
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  Make 
  <div id=flip>
    <div><div>wOrK</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK2</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle2</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything2</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK3</div></div>
  </div>
  AweSoMe!
</div>
```

---

To fix this you will need to add the other `margin-top` offset positions.  Probably something like this:

```css
@keyframes show {
  0%, 12%, 100% {margin-top:-630px;}
  13%, 25% {margin-top:-540px;}
  26%, 38% {margin-top:-450px;}
  39%, 41% {margin-top:-360px;}
  42%, 54% {margin-top:-270px;}
  55%, 67% {margin-top:-180px;}
  68%, 80% {margin-top:-90px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
}
```

It's not perfect, but you get the idea. You'll have to play with the timings on it.  FYI, you'll notice you can use multiple percentages to have the same value, this way you don't need to repeat the value in the keyframe animation.

See it kinda-working below

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  color:#999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:200px;  
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:45%;
  display:block;
}

#flip {
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#flip > div > div {
  color:#fff;
  padding:4px 12px;
  height:45px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
  animation: show 10s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
  background:#42c58a;
}
#flip div:first-child div {
  background:#4ec7f3;
}
#flip div:last-child div {
  background:#DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
  0%, 12%, 100% {margin-top:-630px;}
  13%, 25% {margin-top:-540px;}
  26%, 38% {margin-top:-450px;}
  39%, 41% {margin-top:-360px;}
  42%, 54% {margin-top:-270px;}
  55%, 67% {margin-top:-180px;}
  68%, 80% {margin-top:-90px;}
  99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  Make 
  <div id=flip>
    <div><div>wOrK</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK2</div></div>
    <div><div>lifeStyle2</div></div>
    <div><div>Everything2</div></div>
    <div><div>wOrK3</div></div>
  </div>
  AweSoMe!
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much how I was going to answer but in much more detail. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/zYmRrYQ?editors=0100) with slightly different values that works a little better +1.

Comment: That's much smoother looking than mine, I was just guessing at the keyframe steps

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne it works a little bit better yes but I can't use tags like main, header, section ... it's provoking conflict. Tag names should be unique :-/
So right now i'm trying to perform the answer of FiniteLooper (Thanks)  for now here 
https://www.petrescue.do/test/
with time 20sec and these values:
'@keyframes show {
  0%, 12% {margin-top:-540px;}
  24%, 36% {margin-top:-450px;}
  37%, 49% {margin-top:-360px;}
  50%, 62% {margin-top:-270px;}
  63%, 75% {margin-top:-180px;}
  76%, 88% {margin-top:-90px;}
  89%, 100% {margin-top:0px;}
}'
But could be way better ^^ Tks

Comment: Last update :)  Pretty happy with the actual result with these values ( time show 10s ) Thanks again @FiniteLooper !

`@keyframes show {
  0%, 9% {margin-top:-540px;}
  10%, 22% {margin-top:-450px;}
  23%, 46% {margin-top:-360px;}
  47%, 60% {margin-top:-270px;}
  61%, 75% {margin-top:-180px;}
  76%, 87% {margin-top:-90px;}
  88%, 100% {margin-top:0px;}
}`

Comment: Hi @Phil if FiniteLooper's answer worked for you, you should accept the answer by clicking the ✅.